# Code stops running in the middle of nested for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, runtime-error, nodes

I have some code which is attempting to solve a challenge problem:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import product

def breadthfirstsearch(graph, start, goal):
    if start == goal:
        return [start]
    visited = {start}
    queue = deque([(start, [])])

    while queue:
        current, path = queue.popleft()
        visited.add(current)
        for neighbor in graph[current]:
            if neighbor == goal:
                return path + [current, neighbor]
            if neighbor in visited:
                continue
            queue.append((neighbor, path + [current]))
            visited.add(neighbor)   
    return None
''' 
# this part is irrelevant right now

x = 0 # temp value
final =[]
for i in range(x):
    a, b, c, d = list(map(int, input().split()))
    lne = []
    for j in range(b):
        t = list(map(int, input().split()))
        lne.append(t)
    r = [c, d, lne]
    final.append(r)
'''
roadCounts = 0
final = [[100, 1000, [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16], [16, 17], [17, 18], [18, 19], [19, 20], [20, 21], [21, 22], [22, 23], [23, 24], [24, 25], [25, 26], [26, 27], [27, 28], [28, 29], [29, 30], [30, 31], [31, 32], [32, 33], [33, 34], [34, 35], [35, 36], [36, 37], [37, 38], [38, 39], [39, 40], [40, 41], [41, 42], [42, 43], [43, 44], [44, 45], [45, 46], [46, 47], [47, 48], [48, 49], [49, 50], [50, 51], [51, 52], [52, 53], [53, 54], [54, 55], [55, 56], [56, 57], [57, 58], [58, 59], [59, 60], [60, 61], [61, 62], [62, 63], [63, 64], [64, 65], [65, 66], [66, 67], [67, 68], [68, 69], [69, 70], [70, 71], [71, 72], [72, 73], [73, 74], [74, 75], [75, 76], [76, 77], [77, 78], [78, 79], [79, 80], [80, 81], [81, 82], [82, 83], [83, 84], [84, 85], [85, 86], [86, 87], [87, 88], [88, 89], [89, 90], [90, 91], [91, 92], [92, 93], [93, 94], [94, 95], [95, 96], [96, 97], [97, 98], [98, 99], [99, 100], [100, 101], [101, 102], [102, 103], [103, 104], [104, 105], [105, 106], [106, 107], [107, 108], [108, 109], [109, 110], [110, 111], [111, 112], [112, 113], [113, 114], [114, 115], [115, 116], [116, 117], [117, 118], [118, 119], [119, 120], [120, 121], [121, 122], [122, 123], [123, 124], [124, 125], [125, 126], [126, 127], [127, 128], [128, 129], [129, 130], [130, 131], [131, 132], [132, 133], [133, 134], [134, 135], [135, 136], [136, 137], [137, 138], [138, 139], [139, 140], [140, 141], [141, 142], [142, 143], [143, 144], [144, 145], [145, 146], [146, 147], [147, 148], [148, 149], [149, 150], [150, 151], [151, 152], [152, 153], [153, 154], [154, 155], [155, 156], [156, 157], [157, 158], [158, 159], [159, 160], [160, 161], [161, 162], [162, 163], [163, 164], [164, 165], [165, 166], [166, 167], [167, 168], [168, 169], [169, 170], [170, 171], [171, 172], [172, 173], [173, 174], [174, 175], [175, 176], [176, 177], [177, 178], [178, 179], [179, 180], [180, 181], [181, 182], [182, 183], [183, 184], [184, 185], [185, 186], [186, 187], [187, 188], [188, 189], [189, 190], [190, 191], [191, 192], [192, 193], [193, 194], [194, 195], [195, 196], [196, 197], [197, 198], [198, 199], [199, 200], [200, 201], [201, 202], [202, 203], [203, 204], [204, 205], [205, 206], [206, 207], [207, 208], [208, 209], [209, 210], [210, 211], [211, 212], [212, 213], [213, 214], [214, 215], [215, 216], [216, 217], [217, 218], [218, 219], [219, 220], [220, 221], [221, 222], [222, 223], [223, 224], [224, 225], [225, 226], [226, 227], [227, 228], [228, 229], [229, 230], [230, 231], [231, 232], [232, 233], [233, 234], [234, 235], [235, 236], [236, 237], [237, 238], [238, 239], [239, 240], [240, 241], [241, 242], [242, 243], [243, 244], [244, 245], [245, 246], [246, 247], [247, 248], [248, 249], [249, 250], [250, 251], [251, 252], [252, 253], [253, 254], [254, 255], [255, 256], [256, 257], [257, 258], [258, 259], [259, 260], [260, 261], [261, 262], [262, 263], [263, 264], [264, 265], [265, 266], [266, 267], [267, 268], [268, 269], [269, 270], [270, 271], [271, 272], [272, 273], [273, 274], [274, 275], [275, 276], [276, 277], [277, 278], [278, 279], [279, 280], [280, 281], [281, 282], [282, 283], [283, 284], [284, 285], [285, 286], [286, 287], [287, 288], [288, 289], [289, 290], [290, 291], [291, 292], [292, 293], [293, 294], [294, 295], [295, 296], [296, 297], [297, 298], [298, 299], [299, 300], [300, 301], [301, 302], [302, 303], [303, 304], [304, 305], [305, 306], [306, 307], [307, 308], [308, 309], [309, 310], [310, 311], [311, 312], [312, 313], [313, 314], [314, 315], [315, 316], [316, 317], [317, 318], [318, 319], [319, 320], [320, 321], [321, 322], [322, 323], [323, 324], [324, 325], [325, 326], [326, 327], [327, 328], [328, 329], [329, 330], [330, 331], [331, 332], [332, 333], [333, 334], [334, 335], [335, 336], [336, 337], [337, 338], [338, 339], [339, 340], [340, 341], [341, 342], [342, 343], [343, 344], [344, 345], [345, 346], [346, 347], [347, 348], [348, 349], [349, 350], [350, 351], [351, 352], [352, 353], [353, 354], [354, 355], [355, 356], [356, 357], [357, 358], [358, 359], [359, 360], [360, 361], [361, 362], [362, 363], [363, 364], [364, 365], [365, 366], [366, 367], [367, 368], [368, 369], [369, 370], [370, 371], [371, 372], [372, 373], [373, 374], [374, 375], [375, 376], [376, 377], [377, 378], [378, 379], [379, 380], [380, 381], [381, 382], [382, 383], [383, 384], [384, 385], [385, 386], [386, 387], [387, 388], [388, 389], [389, 390], [390, 391], [391, 392], [392, 393], [393, 394], [394, 395], [395, 396], [396, 397], [397, 398], [398, 399], [399, 400], [400, 401], [401, 402], [402, 403], [403, 404], [404, 405], [405, 406], [406, 407], [407, 408], [408, 409], [409, 410], [410, 411], [411, 412], [412, 413], [413, 414], [414, 415], [415, 416], [416, 417], [417, 418], [418, 419], [419, 420], [420, 421], [421, 422], [422, 423], [423, 424], [424, 425], [425, 426], [426, 427], [427, 428], [428, 429], [429, 430], [430, 431], [431, 432], [432, 433], [433, 434], [434, 435], [435, 436], [436, 437], [437, 438], [438, 439], [439, 440], [440, 441], [441, 442], [442, 443], [443, 444], [444, 445], [445, 446], [446, 447], [447, 448], [448, 449], [449, 450], [450, 451], [451, 452], [452, 453], [453, 454], [454, 455], [455, 456], [456, 457], [457, 458], [458, 459], [459, 460], [460, 461], [461, 462], [462, 463], [463, 464], [464, 465], [465, 466], [466, 467], [467, 468], [468, 469], [469, 470], [470, 471], [471, 472], [472, 473], [473, 474], [474, 475], [475, 476], [476, 477], [477, 478], [478, 479], [479, 480], [480, 481], [481, 482], [482, 483], [483, 484], [484, 485], [485, 486], [486, 487], [487, 488], [488, 489], [489, 490], [490, 491], [491, 492], [492, 493], [493, 494], [494, 495], [495, 496], [496, 497], [497, 498], [498, 499], [499, 500], [500, 501], [501, 502], [502, 503], [503, 504], [504, 505], [505, 506], [506, 507], [507, 508], [508, 509], [509, 510], [510, 511], [511, 512], [512, 513], [513, 514], [514, 515], [515, 516], [516, 517], [517, 518], [518, 519], [519, 520], [520, 521], [521, 522], [522, 523], [523, 524], [524, 525], [525, 526], [526, 527], [527, 528], [528, 529], [529, 530], [530, 531], [531, 532], [532, 533], [533, 534], [534, 535], [535, 536], [536, 537], [537, 538], [538, 539], [539, 540], [540, 541], [541, 542], [542, 543], [543, 544], [544, 545], [545, 546], [546, 547], [547, 548], [548, 549], [549, 550], [550, 551], [551, 552], [552, 553], [553, 554], [554, 555], [555, 556], [556, 557], [557, 558], [558, 559], [559, 560], [560, 561], [561, 562], [562, 563], [563, 564], [564, 565], [565, 566], [566, 567], [567, 568], [568, 569], [569, 570], [570, 571], [571, 572], [572, 573], [573, 574], [574, 575], [575, 576], [576, 577], [577, 578], [578, 579], [579, 580], [580, 581], [581, 582], [582, 583], [583, 584], [584, 585], [585, 586], [586, 587], [587, 588], [588, 589], [589, 590], [590, 591], [591, 592], [592, 593], [593, 594], [594, 595], [595, 596], [596, 597], [597, 598], [598, 599], [599, 600], [600, 601], [601, 602], [602, 603], [603, 604], [604, 605], [605, 606], [606, 607], [607, 608], [608, 609], [609, 610], [610, 611], [611, 612], [612, 613], [613, 614], [614, 615], [615, 616], [616, 617], [617, 618], [618, 619], [619, 620], [620, 621], [621, 622], [622, 623], [623, 624], [624, 625], [625, 626], [626, 627], [627, 628], [628, 629], [629, 630], [630, 631], [631, 632], [632, 633], [633, 634], [634, 635], [635, 636], [636, 637], [637, 638], [638, 639], [639, 640], [640, 641], [641, 642], [642, 643], [643, 644], [644, 645], [645, 646], [646, 647], [647, 648], [648, 649], [649, 650], [650, 651], [651, 652], [652, 653], [653, 654], [654, 655], [655, 656], [656, 657], [657, 658], [658, 659], [659, 660], [660, 661], [661, 662], [662, 663], [663, 664], [664, 665], [665, 666], [666, 667], [667, 668], [668, 669], [669, 670], [670, 671], [671, 672], [672, 673], [673, 674], [674, 675], [675, 676], [676, 677], [677, 678], [678, 679], [679, 680], [680, 681], [681, 682], [682, 683], [683, 684], [684, 685], [685, 686], [686, 687], [687, 688], [688, 689], [689, 690], [690, 691], [691, 692], [692, 693], [693, 694], [694, 695], [695, 696], [696, 697], [697, 698], [698, 699], [699, 700], [700, 701], [701, 702], [702, 703], [703, 704], [704, 705], [705, 706], [706, 707], [707, 708], [708, 709], [709, 710], [710, 711], [711, 712], [712, 713], [713, 714], [714, 715], [715, 716], [716, 717], [717, 718], [718, 719], [719, 720], [720, 721], [721, 722], [722, 723], [723, 724], [724, 725], [725, 726], [726, 727], [727, 728], [728, 729], [729, 730], [730, 731], [731, 732], [732, 733], [733, 734], [734, 735], [735, 736], [736, 737], [737, 738], [738, 739], [739, 740], [740, 741], [741, 742], [742, 743], [743, 744], [744, 745], [745, 746], [746, 747], [747, 748], [748, 749], [749, 750], [750, 751], [751, 752], [752, 753], [753, 754], [754, 755], [755, 756], [756, 757], [757, 758], [758, 759], [759, 760], [760, 761], [761, 762], [762, 763], [763, 764], [764, 765], [765, 766], [766, 767], [767, 768], [768, 769], [769, 770], [770, 771], [771, 772], [772, 773], [773, 774], [774, 775], [775, 776], [776, 777], [777, 778], [778, 779], [779, 780], [780, 781], [781, 782], [782, 783], [783, 784], [784, 785], [785, 786], [786, 787], [787, 788], [788, 789], [789, 790], [790, 791], [791, 792], [792, 793], [793, 794], [794, 795], [795, 796], [796, 797], [797, 798], [798, 799], [799, 800], [800, 801], [801, 802], [802, 803], [803, 804], [804, 805], [805, 806], [806, 807], [807, 808], [808, 809], [809, 810], [810, 811], [811, 812], [812, 813], [813, 814], [814, 815], [815, 816], [816, 817], [817, 818], [818, 819], [819, 820], [820, 821], [821, 822], [822, 823], [823, 824], [824, 825], [825, 826], [826, 827], [827, 828], [828, 829], [829, 830], [830, 831], [831, 832], [832, 833], [833, 834], [834, 835], [835, 836], [836, 837], [837, 838], [838, 839], [839, 840], [840, 841], [841, 842], [842, 843], [843, 844], [844, 845], [845, 846], [846, 847], [847, 848], [848, 849], [849, 850], [850, 851], [851, 852], [852, 853], [853, 854], [854, 855], [855, 856], [856, 857], [857, 858], [858, 859], [859, 860], [860, 861], [861, 862], [862, 863], [863, 864], [864, 865], [865, 866], [866, 867], [867, 868], [868, 869], [869, 870], [870, 871], [871, 872], [872, 873], [873, 874], [874, 875], [875, 876], [876, 877], [877, 878], [878, 879], [879, 880], [880, 881], [881, 882], [882, 883], [883, 884], [884, 885], [885, 886], [886, 887], [887, 888], [888, 889], [889, 890], [890, 891], [891, 892], [892, 893], [893, 894], [894, 895], [895, 896], [896, 897], [897, 898], [898, 899], [899, 900], [900, 901], [901, 902], [902, 903], [903, 904], [904, 905], [905, 906], [906, 907], [907, 908], [908, 909], [909, 910], [910, 911], [911, 912], [912, 913], [913, 914], [914, 915], [915, 916], [916, 917], [917, 918], [918, 919], [919, 920], [920, 921], [921, 922], [922, 923], [923, 924], [924, 925], [925, 926], [926, 927], [927, 928], [928, 929], [929, 930], [930, 931], [931, 932], [932, 933], [933, 934], [934, 935], [935, 936], [936, 937], [937, 938], [938, 939], [939, 940], [940, 941], [941, 942], [942, 943], [943, 944], [944, 945], [945, 946], [946, 947], [947, 948], [948, 949], [949, 950], [950, 951], [951, 952], [952, 953], [953, 954], [954, 955], [955, 956], [956, 957], [957, 958], [958, 959], [959, 960], [960, 961], [961, 962], [962, 963], [963, 964], [964, 965], [965, 966], [966, 967], [967, 968], [968, 969], [969, 970], [970, 971], [971, 972], [972, 973], [973, 974], [974, 975], [975, 976], [976, 977], [977, 978], [978, 979], [979, 980], [980, 981], [981, 982], [982, 983], [983, 984], [984, 985], [985, 986], [986, 987], [987, 988], [988, 989], [989, 990], [990, 991], [991, 992], [992, 993], [993, 994], [994, 995], [995, 996], [996, 997], [997, 998], [998, 999], [999, 1000]]]]
for roadPaths in final:
    home = roadPaths[0]
    school = roadPaths[1]
    cool = roadPaths[2]
    alrd = []
    graph = {}
    for val in cool:
        n1 = val[0]
        n2 = val[1]
        if n1 not in alrd:
            alrd.append(n1)
            graph[n1] = [n2]
        else:
            graph[n1].append(n2)
        if n2 not in alrd:
            alrd.append(n2)
            graph[n2] = [n1]
        else:
            graph[n2].append(n2)


    notAllowed = []
    lis = list(graph.keys())

    path = breadthfirstsearch(graph, home, school)
    for i in lis:
        notAllowed.append([i, i])

    for key, val in graph.items():
        for v in val:
            n = sorted([key, v])
            if n not in notAllowed:
                notAllowed.append(n)

    # OVER HERE OVER HERE
    #START
    for i in range(len(path)-2):
        for j in range(i+2, len(path)):
            n = sorted([path[i], path[j]])
            notAllowed.append(n)

    #END

    possibleRoads = []
    roads = 0
    for i in lis:
        for j in lis:
            if sorted([i, j]) not in notAllowed:
                possibleRoads.append(sorted([i, j]))
                notAllowed.append(sorted([i, j]))
                roads += 1
    print(roads)
```

and this code runs perfectly fine until it gets to this part:

```
    for i in range(len(path)-2):
        for j in range(i+2, len(path)):
            n = sorted([path[i], path[j]])
            notAllowed.append(n)
            print(i)
```

where once i is equal to 898 the program just stops working. Run it on your own environment to see what I mean but does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it? I have tried several different things but nothing is working. The tester for the challenge problem is also giving me a run time error so I feel like a test case similar to this is what is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by stops working?
path does contain 901 elements, you are ranging of two less, it should do nothing more.

Afterwords though, you give you're program a huge pile of work,
by bruteforcing all combinations of roads:
`for i in lis:
        for j in lis:`

Which is about 1000² times in your case.

The program does not stop working, but just is not done, yet.

You can follow your progress like this:

```
left = llis*llis

for i in lis:
    for j in lis:
        if sorted([i, j]) not in notAllowed:
            possibleRoads.append(sorted([i, j]))
            notAllowed.append(sorted([i, j]))
            roads += 1
        left-=1
    pc=round((1-(left/(llis*llis)))*1000)/10
    print("{}%".format(str(pc)))
print("end")
print(roads)
```

I'm now at 1.5% and it took me about 4 minutes.
So maybe you go and find a better solution for this, or build up some patience :)

Comment: Do you have any ideas to make it faster?